# How to attach order status to order item collection?

Tags: orders, collection, order-status

I'm loading a collection of order items like this:

```
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

And I'd like to join to add the order's status to the collection, so that I can filter out incomplete orders via `addFieldToFilter('status', 'complete')`.

How do I join these two things so that I can filter on the parent order's status?

I would paste my various attempts but I think that would probably just add confusion.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `join` method on the `getSelect` object

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->getSelect()->join( array('orders'=> sales_flat_order), 'orders.order_id = main_table.order_id', array('orders.status')); // join on orderid and retrieve the status column
```

Small side note, it's better to specifically state which fields you need instead of using `addAttributeToSelect('*')`

Answer (score 1):

hello try like this...

```
$order_collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('status','Complete' );
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that isn't actually what I'm looking for. You've loaded the `sales/order` collection, when what I need is the `sales/order_item` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to following code. This adds to order customer id, email address and order status to your order item collection.

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
;

$collection
    ->getSelect()
    ->join(
        array('orders'=> 'sales_flat_order'),
        'orders.entity_id=main_table.order_id', 
        array(
            'orders.customer_email',
            'orders.customer_id',
            'orders.status as order_status'
        )
    )
;
```

You can read the additional fields like you normally would.

```
foreach ( $collection as $orderItem ) {
    $status = $orderItem->getOrderStatus();    
}
```